# Fetch and replace data from firestore to make a recent message data feed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a chat app and with each of its messages as a firebase document for each contact. I was wondering if there was a way to fetch the data of the very last message sent for the recent chat feed. The feed will be made up of a list of contacts with their respective recent messages as well as if they have been read or unread.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit ordering of documents in Firestore.  If you want the "last" document, you're going to have to define that order using fields in the document.  If you want the most recently added document, then each document should store a timestamp in a field in the document, and use that field to order a descending query against that field, limiting to a single document.

Comment: I would do that, but I want to iterate over several documents that have their own subcollections. It's an entire tree of documents and subcollections. But they do have a timestamp so I'll try out this solution and see what happens.

Comment: Firestore doesn't have "deep" queries that span multiple collections.  You can only query one collection at a time, or use a collection group query that queries across all collections with the same name.